# Can not find the tag library descriptor of springframework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I'm trying to follow the example of spring JPetStore but I get an error in the JSP pages in the line that references the lib tag spring:

**Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags"**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

What is the URL of this library?

Is there any way to avoid the direct dependence on this URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please tell me the link to download Spring Dependency Jar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Download the Spring dependency jar
2. Place it to the lib folder path is /WEB-INF/lib/spring.jar
3. Then open the web.xml and the sample code is:

   ```
   <taglib>
     <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-location>
   </taglib>
   ```
4. Then the taglib is indicated where the jar file locates in ur system.

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="/WEB-INF/spring.tld" %>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just had found the same solution to the problem and was going to offer it here when I saw your response

Comment: Extracting the TLD from the JAR is not necessary.

Comment: It's strange. When I opened the project in Eclipse, the project showed this error. When I modified the web.xml the error disappeared. But given the comments of Steven Benitez, I took back the change ... and now shows no errors! Why? I dont'know...

Comment: I added a space in the web.xml file, saved and the error was removed for me to. I only have the spring-webmvc.jar in WEB-INF/lib (no tablib declaration)

Answer (score 17):

I know it's an old question, but the tag library `http://www.springframework.org/tags` is provided by `spring-webmvc` package. With Maven it can be added to the project with the following lines to be added in the `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Without Maven, just add that jar to your classpath. In any case it's not necessary to refer the tld file directly, it will be automatically found.

Answer (score 13):

Removing the space between *@* and *taglib* did the trick for me: `<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>`

Comment: my guess is that removing the space did nothing at all. other than ensured that eclipse picked up "a change" on the file and re-validated. i think if you added/removed a space elsewhere it might have worked the same

Comment: Removing/adding space worked only after I added required dependencies for taglib. Removing or adding space did nothing other than re-validating.

Comment: Worked for me as well, but my problem was the `%>` at the end had no space after the closing double-quote.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using maven use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The TLD should be located in the `spring.jar`. Your application won't have any dependency on that URL. It's just used as a unique name to identify the tag library. They could just as well have made the URI "/spring-tags", but using URLs is pretty common place.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add the dependency for springs mvc

tray adding that in your pom

```
<!-- mvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with weblogic 12c and maven I initially while deploying from eclipse (kepler) (deploying from the console gave no errors).

The other solutions given on this page didn't help.

I extracted the *spring.tld spring-form.tld* files of the spring-webmvc jar (which I found in my repository) in the web\WEB-INF folder of my war module;

I did a fresh build; deployed (from eclipse) into weblogic 12c, tested the application and the error was gone;

I removed the *spring.tld spring-form.tld* files again and after deleting; rebuilding and redeploying the application the error didn't show up again.

I double checked whether the files were gone in the war and they were indeed not present.

hope this helps others with a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

I finally configured RAD to build my Maven-based project, but was getting the following exception when I navigate to a page that uses the Spring taglib:

> JSPG0047E: Unable to locate tag library for uri
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.tagfiledep.TagFileDependencyVisitor.visitCustomTagStart(TagFileDependencyVisitor.java:76)
>   ...

The way I had configured my EAR, all the jars were in the EAR, not in the WAR’s WEB-INF/lib. According to the JSP 2.0 spec, I believe tag libs are searched for in all subdirectories of WEB-INF, hence the issue. My solution was to copy the tld files and place under  WEB-INF/lib or  WEB-INF.. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want direct link:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-form.tld

Or from repos:

***JCenter*** : [link](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.springframework%3Aspring-webmvc/view)

***Maven Central*** : [link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-webmvc%7C4.1.6.RELEASE%7Cjar)

And if you need as Gradle dependency:

compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE

More information about spring-form:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another case.

We have several portlets in different portlet application war and all of them use spring. So in order to reduce size of each war, we have created shared libraries for spring jars in the WebSphere Portal server.

However, I came across the same issue as above of not having the spring form tags being referred from the jsp files.

In order to resolve, I have copied the spring-form.tld file into the WEB-INF/ directory and redeployed the war and it worked.

Hope it helps for anyone having a similar issue as mine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem normally appears while copy pasting the tag lib URL from the internet. Usually the quotes `""` in which the URL http://www.springframework.org/tags is embedded might not be correct. Try removing quotes and type them manually. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Spring-Boot, For me cut-paste of below in Pom.xml worked. May be file wasnt in sync.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Core dependencies for tag library:

```
> <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

add external jar of jstl-standard.jar as the external jar by right click on JRE system libraries under configure build path -> build path.
it worked for me!!