# Weblogic - Error when accessing spring taglib

Tags: spring, tags, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm getting an error when i try to access a page with spring taglibs.
During the deploy there are not any error.

Error:

```
personAdd.jsp:2:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. 
Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there 
were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

Weblogic: 12c
Sts: 2.9.1

Any suggestions on what could be wrong, where to look and how/what to fix?

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4219166/980472). Take a look, you answer is there.