# <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %> Not found

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, weblogic

I am getting this exception when deploying a Maven web project through Eclipse to a Weblogic 12c server.

```
student.jsp:1:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    ^----^
```

I have tried adding the Maven Dependencies to the Deployment Assembly to no avail. It works when I manually drop either the .tld or .jar file into /lib in my project prior to deployment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219166/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-of-springframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, long time since posting, but I am quite sure this was a result of how I was creating the project. Used to with Eclipse, I created the web app, then converted to a Maven project. I think it may be a combination of the plugin getting better, or creating a Maven war project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the space after `<%@` and before `taglib` to write it `<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>` ?

I think that it looks more like to a classpath problem but never know, in case it would work...