# CRUD "HTTP Status 404 -" or "error during artefact deployment"

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, crud

I'm trying to create CRUD application and I have "HTTP Status 404". I've started from create easy "HelloWorld" app and then gradually added new pieces. Error appears when I add DataBase part.

**Server Logs**

```
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.705 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 31 2016 19:51:16 UTC
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.5.0
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Андрей\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TaskManager
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.712 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.5
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.713 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.715 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.715 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.716 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Андрей\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TaskManager\conf\logging.properties
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.716 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.717 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Андрей\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TaskManager
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.717 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.5
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.717 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\temp
13-Oct-2016 14:26:24.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Андрей\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\TShell\TShell\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Jar2Exe Wizard\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.433 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.482 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.486 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.489 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2510 ms
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.531 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.531 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.549 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.563 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:25.565 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 75 ms
Connected to server
[2016-10-13 02:26:25,672] Artifact TaskManager:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13-Oct-2016 14:26:35.639 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Oct-2016 14:26:35.642 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\manager
13-Oct-2016 14:26:36.051 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\servers\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\manager has finished in 408 ms
13-Oct-2016 14:26:36.240 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
13-Oct-2016 14:26:36.629 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Oct 13 14:26:36 KRAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
13-Oct-2016 14:26:36.961 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class ru.yandex.pirojok171.config.RootConfig]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:37.758 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1517 ms
13-Oct-2016 14:26:37.766 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
13-Oct-2016 14:26:37.779 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Oct 13 14:26:37 KRAT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13-Oct-2016 14:26:37.792 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class ru.yandex.pirojok171.config.WebConfig]
13-Oct-2016 14:26:38.264 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AutoProxyRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(AutoProxyRegistrar.java:63)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:674)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2016-10-13 02:26:38,378] Artifact TaskManager:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-10-13 02:26:38,379] Artifact TaskManager:war exploded: Deploy took 12 706 milliseconds
13-Oct-2016 14:26:38.881 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
13-Oct-2016 14:26:39.046 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Root mapping to handler 'taskManagerController'
13-Oct-2016 14:26:39.378 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 497 ms
13-Oct-2016 14:26:39.511 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:26:39.618 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:26:40.369 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:26:40.801 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:27:35.986 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:28:35.986 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:29:36.005 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13-Oct-2016 14:30:36.017 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**DataBase config.**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.yandex.pirojok171.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan("ru.yandex.pirojok171")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;



    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("db.entity.package"));
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperies());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        ds.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.initialSize")));
        ds.setMinIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minIdle")));
        ds.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.maxIdle")));
        ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis")));
        ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minEvictableTimeMills")));
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.testOnBorrow")));
        ds.setValidationQuery(env.getRequiredProperty("db.validationQuery"));
        return ds;
    }

    public Properties getHibernateProperies() {
        try{
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties");
            properties.load(is);
            return properties;
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't found 'hibernate.propeties' in classpath! ",e);
        }
    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ru.yandex.pirojok171")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**RootConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
}
```

**WebInit**

```
@Configuration
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**TaskController**

```
@Controller
public class TaskManagerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <properties>
        <spring-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <hibernate-version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate-version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>6.0.4</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <commons-dbcp2.version>2.${jta.version}</commons-dbcp2.version>
        <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1211.jre7</postgresql.version>
        <jackson-databind.version>2.5.3</jackson-databind.version>
        <javaee-web-api.version>7.0</javaee-web-api.version>
        <spring-orm.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-orm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-orm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

*Project structure:*

[image: Project structure]

I've used this construction(without web.xml and servlet.xml), because it gave me "error during artifact department"(context.xml wasn't found).

Thank you for any help or comments.

Comment: This error means, that something went wrong - some exception was thrown. Without full logs it would be hard to help you

Comment: You are definetly right, i forgot about them, sorry

Comment: it says your `TLD` not found (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219166/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-of-springframework)