# Spring- JSF War Deployment on Tomcat 9 fails(no TLDS Jars found)

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsf, spring-tld

I want to create a JSF Spring Application and my war is not deployed, because of this error:

```
09-Oct-2018 12:02:54.383 INFORMATION [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Unable to process ServletContainerInitializer for [com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer]. This is most likely due to a class defined in the @HandlesTypes annotation being missing. Enable DEBUG level logging for the full stack trace.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.050 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.053 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.18.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.080 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.18.jar].
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.081 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.082 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.083 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api-2.1.7.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.083 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.084 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.085 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/afterdark-1.0.10.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.087 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.088 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.089 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.089 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.090 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.092 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/modelmapper-0.7.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.092 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.093 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.094 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-6.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.095 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.097 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.097 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.098 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.099 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.099 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.100 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.9.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.101 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.101 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.102 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/mapstruct-jdk8-1.1.0.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.102 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.103 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jcl-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.104 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.105 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/Tobi/IdeaProjects/games/GamesFrontend/target/exploded/games.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
```

org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    09-Oct-2018 12:02:56.143 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/frontend]]

Can someone help me with this error. This is the debug log of my tomcat.

My project is a multi Module Maven Project. The head pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gamescreation</groupId>
    <artifactId>games</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>GamesBackend</module>
        <module>PictureUpload</module>
        <module>DeviceBackend</module>
        <module>GamesFrontend</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>games</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>

    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->



        <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet Spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>games</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exploded/${project.build.finalName}.war
                    </webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And the pom of the sub module looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>games</artifactId>
        <groupId>gamescreation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>GamesFrontend</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.themes/afterdark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>afterdark</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem, and can tell me what is ment by TLDs jars, because I dont know what is meant by this. If you need any other information about my problem feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance, I hope someone can help me soon.

Comment: About the TLD jars; have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219166/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-of-springframework/4222768

Comment: These are not errors but 'FEIN' logging... Sure there is no other real cause visible for the problem of starting the app?

Comment: there were some exception lines more which where too long for the post. I will add them to a new comment

Comment: this is the complete exception:https://hastebin.com/iqivukofix.sql

Comment: jsf spring application? o.O what is it like?

Comment: Is there a SecurityManager enabled? Try again after disabling it. It might prevent com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getInitContextServletContextMap() from making private field FacesContext.initContextServletContext accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSF API 2.1 and JSF Implementation 2.2 do not match. Upgrade your API (jsf-api, javax.faces-api)  to 2.2.28 or downgrade your implementation (jsf-impl).

```
com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getInitContextServletContextMap()
```

returns `null` which leads to the `NullPointerException` later on.
`Null` is returned, because this method tries to access the static private field `FacesContext.initContextServletContext` which does not exist in your API version of JSF.